# ASP.NET MVC5 Call JavaScript function from Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to call JavaScript function, to which I pass parameter, from MVC5 Partial view.

I have declared the function `addItem(item)` in separate JS file at the top of the file, before `$(document).ready(function {})` function.

I have tried the following code:

```
@foreach (string item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
{
    TempData["Item"] = item;
    <script type="text/javascript">addItem(@TempData["Item"]);</script>
}
```

And the following:

```
@foreach (string item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">addItem(item);</script>
}
```

both tries end up with the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: theValueOfMyItem is not defined`.

I even tried this:

```
@foreach (string item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
{
    addItem(item);
}
```

but as expected, this gives me error `The name 'addItem' does not exist in the current context`.

So my question is:

Can I call JS function with parameter from partial view, and if possible what is the proper way of doing this?

### Edit 1

After the suggestions of *Carsten Løvbo Andersen* and *Satpal* I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: addItem is not a function`.

Here is how I defined the function:

```
function addItem(item) {
    // processing...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it works but have you tried `addItem('@item')`

Comment: Thanks for fast replay. Still not working. Check my edit.

Comment: you want to use 'addItem(item)' function in partial view and the function is declared in MainView??

Comment: @9-5xaero Read my answer

Answer (score 2):

In your Partial View 1st convert `Items` List into Javascript Array and use javascript `for` loop to call your `addItem` method.

```cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var itemArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Items"] as List<string>));

        for (var item in itemsArray) {
            //call your javascript method with param item
            addItem(item);
        }
    })
</script>
```

another option with c# `foreach` loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            @foreach (var item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
            {   //your javascript method with param item.
                @:addItem(@item);
            }
        })
</script>
```

or

```cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var itemsArray = [];
        @foreach (var item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
        {
            @:itemsArray.push("@item");
        }


        for (var item in itemsArray) {
            //call your javascript method with param item
            addItem(item);
        }
    })


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Umair, but I already found different approach to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `item` in quotes to be treated as string otherwise it will be treated as variables, thus the error.

```
<script>addItem("@item");</script>
```

Comment: What silly me, that I have missed that X.X, but still not working. Check my edit.

Comment: @9-5xaero, `addItem()` is not accessible

Comment: but my function is declared in global scope (as I mentioned in the beginning of my question), how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout page define a section:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

and now you can render your code from your Partial directly to the section

```
<div>Some DIV</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        @foreach (string item in (TempData["Items"] as List<string>))
        {
            addItem('@item');
        }
    </script>
}
<div>Some DIV</div>
<!-- You can mix it up. Everything outside of the @section will be treated as normal markup. -->
```

Perhaps you mind reading this article
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/using-sections-and-partials-to-manage-razor-views.htm

Comment: Thank you Martin, but the `foreach` loop is only little part from my partial view.

Comment: The sction is just a part of your partial view. i will update my anser

Comment: Thank you Martin, but this solution still do not work for me. Never mind, I will search for another solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, put your data in a global variable

```
 `<script>
    var items = @(TempData["Items"] as List<string>); 
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        addItem(item);
    }
  </script>`
```

Comment: Thank you SoftwareNerd, but the provided sample do not work. Never mind, I will search for another solution to my problem :)